# how to create a json string to pass it ot create_table()

Tags: python, json, boto

For create_table function of boto, I want following string

```
'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName': 'Id','AttributeType': 'N'},{'AttributeName': 'orgId','AttributeType': 'S'}]

'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': 'orgId','KeyType': 'HASH'},{'AttributeName': 'Id','KeyType': 'RANGE'}]

'ProvisionedThroughput': {'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,'WriteCapacityUnits': 1}
```

I want to replace the value with the variables, I tried following ways but it didnt work.

```
attribute_definition="'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName':"+hash_attribute_name+",'AttributeType':"+hash_attribute_type+"},{'AttributeName': "+range_attribute_name+",'AttributeType': "+range_attribute_type+"}]"

key_schema="'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': "+hash_attribute_name+",'KeyType': 'HASH'},{'AttributeName': "+hash_attribute_type+",'KeyType': 'RANGE'}]"

capacity="'ProvisionedThroughput': {'ReadCapacityUnits': "+read_capacity+",'WriteCapacityUnits': "+write_capacity+"}"
```

Then I tried to create a list as below.

```
attribute_definition={'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName':hash_attribute_name,'AttributeType':hash_attribute_type},{'AttributeName': range_attribute_name,'AttributeType': range_attribute_type}]}

key_schema={'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': hash_attribute_name,'KeyType': 'HASH'},{'AttributeName': hash_attribute_type,'KeyType': 'RANGE'}]}

capacity={'ProvisionedThroughput': {'ReadCapacityUnits': read_capacity,'WriteCapacityUnits': write_capacity}
```

It throwed following error: `print ("attribute_definition")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I tried to convert the string to the json using json.loads() too

```
attribute_definition=json.loads("{'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName':"+hash_attribute_name+",'AttributeType':"+hash_attribute_type+"},{'AttributeName': "+range_attribute_name+",'AttributeType': "+range_attribute_type+"}]}")

key_schema=json.loads("{'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': "+hash_attribute_name+",'KeyType': 'HASH'},{'AttributeName': "+hash_attribute_type+",'KeyType': 'RANGE'}]}")

capacity=json.loads("{'ProvisionedThroughput': {'ReadCapacityUnits': "+read_capacity+",'WriteCapacityUnits': "+write_capacity+"}}")
```

found following error: `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

I want to pass this strings or list to the create_table function to create table.

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try json.dumps?

```
    >>> hash_attribute_name = 'Id'
    >>> hash_attribute_type = 'N'
    >>> range_attribute_name = 'orgId'
    >>> range_attribute_type = 'S'
    >>> attribute_definition={'AttributeDefinitions':[{'AttributeName':hash_attribute_name,'AttributeType':hash_attribute_type},{'AttributeName': range_attribute_name,'AttributeType': range_attribute_type}]}
    >>> attribute_definition
    {'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName': 'Id', 'AttributeType': 'N'}, {'AttributeName': 'orgId', 'AttributeType': 'S'}]}
    >>> import json
    >>> json.dumps(attribute_definition)
    '{"AttributeDefinitions": [{"AttributeName": "Id", "AttributeType": "N"}, {"AttributeName": "orgId", "AttributeType": "S"}]}'
```

Comment: it does not work :(, it still does not convert it as list.